# ERROR:aiohttp.web:Error handling request

Tags: python-3.x, web, aiohttp

i want to implement account register in my web.  everything is running ok but one error, i can not insert account information in my aiomysql. there is the traceback:

```
INFO:root:Request: POST /api/users
INFO:root:check user: POST /api/users
INFO:root:Response handler...
INFO:root:call with args: {'passwd': '1a4eb93dd425112e9b64374172fede31d85c462d', 'email': 'mike@163.com', 'name': 'mike'}
INFO:root:SQL: select `id`, `created_at`, `image`, `admin`, `passwd`, `name`, `email` from `users` where email=?
INFO:root:rows returned: 0
INFO:root:SQL: insert into `users` (`created_at`, `image`, `admin`, `passwd`, `name`, `email`, `id`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ERROR:aiohttp.web:Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/server.py", line 266, in start
    yield from self.handle_request(message, payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 87, in handle_request
    resp = yield from handler(request)
  File "/home/carrot/hqinawesomewebapp/www/app.py", line 46, in logger
    return (await handler(request))
  File "/home/carrot/hqinawesomewebapp/www/app.py", line 61, in auth
    return (await handler(request))
  File "/home/carrot/hqinawesomewebapp/www/app.py", line 80, in response
    r = await handler(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 219, in coro
    res = yield from await_meth()
  File "/home/carrot/hqinawesomewebapp/www/coroweb.py", line 136, in __call__
    r = await self._func(**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 219, in coro
    res = yield from await_meth()
  File "/home/carrot/hqinawesomewebapp/www/handlers.py", line 174, in api_register_user
    await user.save()
  File "/home/carrot/hqinawesomewebapp/www/orm.py", line 218, in save
    rows = await execute(self.__insert__, args)
  File "/home/carrot/hqinawesomewebapp/www/orm.py", line 53, in execute
    await cur.execute(sql.replace('?', '%s'), args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiomysql/cursors.py", line 237, in execute
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiomysql/cursors.py", line 196, in _escape_args
    return tuple(conn.escape(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiomysql/cursors.py", line 196, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(conn.escape(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 356, in escape
    return escape_item(obj, self._charset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 27, in escape_item
    val = encoder(val, mapping)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 110, in escape_unicode
    return u"'%s'" % _escape_unicode(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 73, in _escape_unicode
    return value.translate(_escape_table)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

in my case, i can do select operation, so my orm.py is ok. but when insert a new account , the page will occur this:
**"There is something wrong with Internet as 500 (HTTP) "** 
 how can fix it? thx :-)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you a passing a function (`func`) into SQL call as argument instead of function call result (`func()`).

Answer (score 0):

in my middlewares has a function named auth_factory to verify the user:

```
async def auth_factory(app, handler):
    async def auth(request):
        logging.info('check user: %s %s' % (request.method, request.path))
        request.__user__ = None
        cookie_str = request.cookies.get(COOKIE_NAME)
        if cookie_str:
            user = await cookie2user(cookie_str)
            if user:
                # i wrong here
                logging.info('set current user: %s' % user.email)
                ...
```

i got an error in **user.email** such as **user.eamil**
then everything is ok
why this middlerwares function impact so big ?
i even can not insert data into mysql, these two thing has some relationship?